# Can't build project with android-ndk and Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio

I have an android project with FFmpeg and other external libraries.  I downloaded the latest version of the ndk (ndk-r10) and am running Android Studio 0.8.0.  I am also running Windows 8 64bit with the latest version of cygwin.

My project builds without issue and I added the ndk.dir to local.properties.  When I try to run I get this error message:

```
The System cannot find the path specified

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\John1\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk-r10\ndk-build.cmd

NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null      
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\John1\AndroidstudioProjects\android-project\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk 
APP_PLATFORM=android-18 
NDK_OUT=C:\Users\John1\AndroidstudioProjects\android-project\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj 
NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\John1\AndroidstudioProjects\android-project\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib 
APP_ABI=all

Error Code:
    1
Output:
    The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Looking for advice.  Thank you.

Comment: are these paths correct: `C:\Users\John1\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk-r10\ndk-build.cmd`, `C:\Users\John1\AndroidstudioProjects\android-project\app\build\`?

Comment: Yes, the ndk-build.cmd is definitely correct and C:\Users\John1\AndroidstudioProjects\android-project\app\build does exist (inside are two sub-folders, generated and intermediates)

Comment: @nyc0202034 are you building using gradle?

Comment: @sujithvm yes I am using gradle in Android studio

Comment: ndk-r10 supports 64 bit. If you would like to compile to for 32 bit targets you need to specify APP_ABI:=all32. Also use the default toolchain that is available. Check your application.mk to make sure it is set to default

Comment: @g3m I don't have an application.mk only an android.mk file.  Please advise.

Comment: I also noticed that the intermediates folder exists but is not part of the project.  Will that effect anything?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

with Android Studio, NDK support is preliminary and your *.mk files are ignored.
You can make Android Studio/gradle reuse them by deactivating the default NDK integration, make it call ndk-build(.cmd) by itself, and use standard `libs/` location for integrating .so files:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig{
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 101
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
}
```

If you need more information, here is my blog post on this topic: http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

Comment: Doing this hides "c" folder from project, so I can't open c files from Android Studio. Is there any workaround?

Comment: after doing this getting this error "A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd'' "

Comment: read the logs to see the error. Maybe the ndk directory hasn't been added to your environment path?

Comment: NB : These edits should be made to `build.gradle` file, when using react-native this is not straightforward as everything is abstracted, hope it helps.

Comment: @ph0b I am using android-studio3.5 and ndk21r. why ndk-build is not running in latest version of ndk. is there any issue with latest build.