# android.useDeprecatedNdk = true Why become gray?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

[image]

`android.useDeprecatedNdk = true` added `gradle.properties` remains gray.

If you try to build in a terminal:

[image]

I get an error and white set the `android.useDeprecatedNdk = true`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just update your gradle plugin and NDK plugin and then clean your project, rebuild it

Comment: A plug -in version of ndk was updated to "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4"

gradle was also updated to 2.14

Then it became here a clean build and rebuild

The situation has not changed

Comment: Check this - 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052564/cant-build-project-with-android-ndk-and-android-studio  2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453085/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugndk-failed-to-run-this-command-ndk